# Bevel question: it is possible to bevel in different directions?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bevel

Here is a cube with the edge beveled and behind that is a normal cube to better explain.

1
[image]

My question is: is there a way to bevel an edge so that is not uniform as in picture 1?

In picture 2 I created the bevel I want, but I had to use a loop cut which is not what I'm looking for.

2
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

..Expanding on @francois gibon's answer..

- in Vertex Mode on the corner-vertex, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it, dragging slightly in the direction of interest, and right-clicking to cancel the move. (Don't deselect)
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the duplicate vertex along the edge to the point you want the bevel to stop.
- Repeat for the other direction(s)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the corner with 'Width Type: Percent', to 100%. If the bevel tool is already set up from previous use, that's just dragging the bevel as far as it will go.
- With all vertices selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> merge > 'By
  Distance', to tidy away the duplicates.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only way to do a non uniform bevel is to use "width type: percent", but it probably won't work for what you want to do... it's easy enough to set the gizmo on the "fixed" face, then use the transform tool on the newly created bevel faces to scale them to your liking (don't forget to set the pivot point to cursor).

Answer (score 1):

You can scale your object, apply the bevel, then scale it back again.

Specifically, let's say you want the bevel to be 50% smaller in the x-direction:

1. In *Object Mode*, change the x-scale from 1 to 2, then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and *Apply Scale*. Now your object is twice as long in the x-direction.
2. In *Edit Mode*, apply the bevel. The bevel will be uniform in all directions.
3. In *Object Mode*, change the x-scale from $1$ to $.5$, then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and *Apply Scale*. The bevel will now be 50% smaller in the x-direction.